# Where would I set the responseType?

Tags: angularjs

If the following was returning an arraybuffer, where would I set the responseType?

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user, getResponseHeaders){
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save(function(user, putResponseHeaders) {
    //user => saved user object
    //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
  });
});
```

I tried doing:

```
var headers = {responseType: 'arraybufer'}

User.get(({userId:123},function(user,headers){...
```

but when I console.log(headers) it says undefined

Comment: It would be wiser to use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for downloading binary data. The [$resource service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) is intended for interaction with [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) server-side sources.

Comment: @georgeawg, but i the event of using $resource, how would i achieve it?

Comment: It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. Under-the-hood it uses [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) which only works with JavaScript objects or JavaScript arrays.

Comment: @georgeawg - Ah...my understanding of javascript isn't that great...thanks

Answer (score -1):

**isArray** – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array, see returns section.

**transformResponse** – {function(data, headersGetter)|Array.} – transform function or an array of such functions. The transform function takes the http response body and headers and returns its transformed (typically deserialized) version. By default, transformResponse will contain one function that checks if the response looks like a JSON string and deserializes it using angular.fromJson. To prevent this behavior, set transformResponse to an empty array: transformResponse: []

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
angular.module('itemServices', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('Item', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
      return $resource('items/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
          query: {
            isArray: true,
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            transformResponse: function (data) {
              return angular.fromJson(data).body.rows
            }
          },
          get: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}},
          save: {method: 'POST'},
          update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}},
          delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {} }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: I saw this same code, but it didn't make sense to me

Comment: `$resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'},{
          query: {
            isArray: true,
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            transformResponse: function (data) {
              return angular.fromJson(data).body.rows
            }
          }}
        });`